# Using PMD 5.1 rules in maven plugin

Tags: maven, pmd

I am using the PMD 3.1 maven plugin and it does not seem to recognise rules > 5.0.

ie.  `AvoidProtectedMethodInFinalClassNotExtending` is not found when I do a maven build.

`Failure executing PMD: Unable to find referenced rule AvoidProtectedMethodInFinalClassNotExtending; perhaps the rule name is mispelled?`

I have set the target JDK to use 1.7

```
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>au.com.patrick.vts.build.tools</groupId>
                    <artifactId>build-tools</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>

                <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
                <targetJdk>${java-version}</targetJdk>
                <linkXRef>true</linkXRef>

            </configuration>                    
            <executions>
                  <execution>
                     <id>validate</id>
                     <phase>validate</phase>
                     <goals>
                       <goal>check</goal>
                     </goals>
                   </execution>
                   <execution>
                     <id>compile</id>
                     <phase>verify</phase>
                     <goals>
                       <goal>check</goal>
                     </goals>
                   </execution>
                </executions>
          </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current version 3.1 of maven-pmd-plugin uses PMD 5.0.5 and does not support 5.1 rules. There is an open ticket at the issue tracker to [release a new version with PMD 5.1](http://jira.codehaus.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/MPMD-182). All you can do at the moment is vote the issue up and hope it gets resolved soon or fix the issue yourself.

Comment: You could also use [sonar](http://www.sonarqube.org) to do static code analysis.  I see [sonar-pmd-plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/PMD+Plugin) supports pmd-5.1.1.